# How to center a table in MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, migradoc

Sorry for I am just beginner of PDFsharp. Currently I am learning the MigraDoc. Is there any example for center the Table in a section? Thanks.

Comment: you want to create a pdf in c# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MigraDoc you can set the left indent of the table. Knowing the width of the page and the width of the table, it is simple to calculate the left indent to get a centered table.

Set `table.Rows.LeftIndent` as needed.